# Error fbauth2 IOS 9, como consertar?

Tags: ios, swift

Tento compilar mesmo com o `auth2` já adicionado e o erro continua, alguém tem ideia do que seja?

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException',
>   reason: 'fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under
>   LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0'

```html
<dict>
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>en</string>
 <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
 <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
 <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
 <string>6.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
 <string>APPL</string>
 <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>1.7.5</string>
 <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
 <string>????</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>1.7.5</string>
 <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
 <string>Main</string>
 <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <array>
  <string>armv7</string>
 </array>
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>
 <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
 <array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
 </array>
 <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>fb</string>
  <string>fbapi20130214</string>
  <string>fbapi20130410</string>
  <string>fbapi20130702</string>
  <string>fbapi20131010</string>
  <string>fbapi20131219</string>
  <string>fbapi20140410</string>
  <string>fbapi20140116</string>
  <string>fbapi20150313</string>
  <string>fbapi20150629</string>
  <string>fbauth</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150128</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150218</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-platform-20150305</string>
  <string>fb-messenger</string>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
 </array>
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>fb1717015255196904</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
 <key>FacebookAppID</key>
 <string>1717015255196904</string>
 <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
 <string>Tinder</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Este erro ocorre tanto no simulador quanto no aparelho?

Comment: só testei no simulador, e ta ocorrendo la @IgorCastañedaFerreira